# Found typo causing error in CRM_Utils_System_DrupalBase->formatResourceUrl()

Tags: civicrm-home

On CiviCRM System Status page I get a permanent error message on the top of the page.

*Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/clients/client5/web16/websites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/angular-modules.aa49fb2433945dcf4a451bb96fb1a0e9.js) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/clients/client5/web16/web:/var/www/clients/client5/web16/private:/var/www/clients/client5/web16/tmp:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin) in CRM_Utils_System_DrupalBase->formatResourceUrl() function (/var/www/clients/client5/web16/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/DrupalBase.php line 126.).*

In CRM_Utils_System_DrupalBase->formatResourceUrl() function, in line 126, I think there is a typo: if I use `if (file_exists(DRUPAL_ROOT .'/'. $file)) {` 
the error message disappears. In the original text the '/' is missing: `if (file_exists(DRUPAL_ROOT . $file)) {`

Is it a bug, or I made some mistake?

Comment: given lots of sites are not reporting this issue i would tend to assume the latter ;-( maybe a permissions issue on a directory?

Answer (score 1):

Your code path is slightly different from your files path:

code: **`.../web16/web/sites/...`**

files: **`.../web16/websites/...`**

That looks like a typo - check your directories and resources settings at `Administer > System Settings > Directories` and `Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs`

Comment: wow. sharp eyes.

Comment: No differences, and the help page shows, that CiviCRM recognizes the correct path with trailing "/".

Comment: Some time later comes an error came up in the same context: there are some _SERVER values missing. The error's reason was that OPcache AND xcache were enabled on the server. After disabling OPcache, those errors disappeared. Perhaps can be this the solution?